# Is there any free end-to-end encrypted email service?

Tags: email, security, encryption

Any service like HushMail or CryptoMail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We built BunkerMail.com to show off our full web-based PKI system.

We distribute RSA Key pairs to each user by hiding them inside of digital images and placing them on the user's box.  We operate on the image and the crypto-keys with flash web widgets which allows us to do end point encryption.

BunkerMail.com encrypts all attachments and a private note at the end point and decrypts the message only at the receiver's machine.

You can go send a few messages for free at bunkermail.com to see how you like it.

--TM

Answer (score 4):

Building off of the GnuPG suggestion, using Thunderbird in conjunction with the Enigmail extension allows you to encrypt email using the PGP (Pretty Good Privacy) encryption scheme. Some years back, Lifehacker put together this excellent tutorial on setting it up on your computer.

http://lifehacker.com/180878/how-to-encrypt-your-email

Basically, you need to install the windows binary of GnuPGP, install the Enigmail extension, and generate your public/private key pair.

Comment: the OP did not say they were on windows.

Answer (score 2):

- [S-Mail](http://s-mail.com/)
- [Send Inc](https://www.sendinc.com/)
- [Lock bin](https://lockbin.com/)
- [Z-Sentry](https://zsentry.com/zmail/emailsecurity.html)

Else, why not use [GnuPG](http://www.gnupg.org/) to encrypt it ?